# VueJS: Complete dynamic component transition before rendering new component

Tags: css, vue.js

I have some components that i swap out using VueJs's dynamic component option. I set up transitions on the dynamic component. My issue is as follows:
-Currently, if a change the current view(or component) the transition effect starts(the leave transition)
-As soon as the transition effect begins the next view/component starts its own transition. In essence, both transitions occur simultaneously. What i want is for the (leave) transition for the first component to complete before the (enter) transition for the new component begins.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>Current page: {{currentView}}</div>
        <img src="./assets/logo.png">
        <transition name="fade">
            <component @stateCPchanged="changeView" v-bind:is="currentView"></component>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import numberPage from './components/NumberPage.vue'
    import otpPage from './components/OtpPage.vue'
    import redirectPage from './components/RedirectPage.vue'
    import state from './state.js'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                currentView: state.currentPage
            }
        },
        components: {
            numberPage: numberPage,
            otpPage: otpPage,
            redirectPage: redirectPage
        }, 
        methods: {
            changeView() {
                this.currentView = state.currentPage
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .fade-enter-active {
        transition: all 0.4s
    }
    .fade-enter {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: 90px;
    }
    .fade-leave-active {
        transition: all 0.4s;
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left: -100px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`mode="out-in"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly solve it, but this can reduce the effect of overlapping of transitions.

You can use [cubic-bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67) functions to your advantage, by controlling  when the transition will be fast during the duration.

You can use `ease-out` CSS property on the moving out component, so transition will be : fast/abrupt at the beginning, slow at the end. Use `ease-in` on the component moving in, so transition will be: slow at the beginning, fast/abrupt at the end, giving you overall effect. More details [here](https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/).