# Vuejs: transition for async component and its loading component

Tags: vue.js

`Vue.component('AsyncComponent', () => ({
  component: import('async-component'),
  loading: LoadingComponent
}))`

How to implement `<transition>` between `AsyncComponent` and `LoadingComponent` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709855/vuejs-complete-dynamic-component-transition-before-rendering-new-component

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks but that may not relate to my problem

Comment: From what I saw Vue do this automatically. Just wrap your async-component with transition.